# How to set operators output in jQuery into thousands separators and 2 decimals points?

Tags: jquery

I have these html input to calculate two input 1 & 2 and display the result into the input 3:

```
<input type="text" class="inputdecimals" id="txt_balance_dec" name="txt_balance_dec" value="0.00">
<input type="text" class="inputdecimals" id="txt_nett_dec"    name="txt_nett_dec"    value="0.00"readonly>


<input type="text" class="inputdecimals" id="txt_balance_nov" name="txt_balance_nov" value="0.00">
```

Here's the jQuery for the inputdecimals :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $('input.inputdecimals').keyup(function(event) {
            if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
            $(this).val(function(index, value) {
              return value
              .replace(/[^\d.]/g, "")
              .replace(/^(\d*\.)(.*)\.(.*)$/, '$1$2$3')
              .replace(/\.(\d{2})\d+/, '.$1')
              .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
              ;
            });
          });
    });
</script>
```

My goal is to subtract the value (**txt_bal_dec** - **txt_bal_nov**) and display the total into **txt_nett_dec**.

Since my input HTML input already change the value into thousand separators and 2 decimals point, output did not show as I want.

for example 10,000.00 - 6,000.00 is equal to 6, not 6,000.00 (Picture below)

[image]

I'm not sure how to replace the thousand separator first and then calculate while keep maintain the 2 decimals. when show the output i need to put back the thousand separator and 2 decimals.

My jQuery calculation as below. Sorry, I'm not really good in jQuery.

```
$("#txt_balance_dec").keyup(function() {
        var bal_dec = parseFloat($(this).val(), 2);
        var bal_nov = parseFloat($('#txt_balance_nov').val(), 2);
        var result = bal_dec - bal_nov;
        $('#txt_nett_dec').val(result);
    });
```

Appreciate if someone can help me to fix this problem. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to strip all commas out of the string *before* you attempt to parse it, as parsing a number with commas will only parse *up to* the first comma.

```
//For example           Result
parseFloat("5,4,3")     // 5
parseFloat("15,000")    // 15
parseFloat("123,456")   // 123
```

This can be done using a simple replace: `.replace(/,/g,'');`

---

I've also made a few changes just to tidy up:

- Made a function that does both `replace` and `parseFloat` called `parseCurrency`, to make it easily reusable
- Put your formatting into a function called `formatCurrency`, to make it easily reusable
- Made `dec_balance` and `nov_balance` inputs can share an event, since a change to either should force a `net` recalculation

```js
const formatCurrency = (str) => (""+str).replace(/[^\d.]/g, "").replace(/^(\d*\.)(.*)\.(.*)$/, '$1$2$3').replace(/\.(\d{2})\d+/, '.$1').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
const parseCurrency = (str) => str.replace(/,/g,'');

$('input.inputdecimals').keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
  $(this).val((i,v) => formatCurrency(v));
});

$("#txt_balance_dec, #txt_balance_nov").keyup(function() {
  var bal_dec = parseCurrency( $("#txt_balance_dec").val() );
  var bal_nov = parseCurrency( $("#txt_balance_nov").val() );
  var result = bal_dec - bal_nov;
  $('#txt_nett_dec').val(formatCurrency(result));
});
```

```css
input { display: block; margin: 10px 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Dec <input type="text" class="inputdecimals" id="txt_balance_dec" name="txt_balance_dec" value="0.00">
Nov <input type="text" class="inputdecimals" id="txt_balance_nov" name="txt_balance_nov" value="0.00">
Net <input type="text" class="inputdecimals" id="txt_nett_dec" name="txt_nett_dec" value="0.00" readonly>
```

(*It's also worth noting that your formatting function seems to strip `-`, therefore the `net` will be an absolute value.*)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll try it first . thanks btw.

Comment: Hi. it works. but how can I display the nett value also have thousand separator and 2 decimals points ? thanks .

Comment: I try your snippet. value dec 1000.00 - value 2000.00 equal to 1000 ? it should be -1000.00

Comment: Yes, I made specific note of this. Look at the bottom of my answer. Your formatting function removes the `-` from negative numbers.

Comment: can you update your answer so the total can accept negative value ?

Comment: Your formatting function is a combination of intricate regexes that I don't plan on dissecting, unfortunately. The quickest solution would be to change `formatCurrency(result)` to just `result`, though the net would then not have commas.

Comment: I see. I'm guess i'm gonna open new question. thanks.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again. I already have the answer to get the negative value. But can you help me to display the formatCurrency that always display 1 decimals point ? Right now, regex above only display the value of 20 as 20 . My goal is to display 20.0 for the value 20 .appreciate if you can help me. thanks.

Comment: @Rozaimi You can use [`.toFixed(1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) on a number to force it to one decimal place. If you're working with a string, you'll need to convert it to a number first, using `parseInt(...)`, `Number(...)`, or in this example, the unary `+` operator: `var str = "20"; var newStr = (+str).toFixed(1);`